# curl nss error -5938

Tags: linux, curl

I am trying one curl command on different servers. One is working and the other one is reporting "nss error -5938".

Server1:

> 1. OS:
>
>    Linux 4.1.12-61.1.10.el6uek.x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> 2. CURL -V:
>
>    curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1
>      Basic ECC    zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2 Protocols: tftp ftp
>      telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp Features:
>      GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
> 3. Command Running Status:Error
>
>    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
>      HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
>      HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
>
>    - Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
>    - Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
>    - CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
>        CApath: none
>    - NSS error -5938
>    - Closing connection #0
>    - SSL connect error
>        curl: (35) SSL connect error

Server2:

> 1. OS:
>
> Linux 412c25016c7b 4.1.12-37.5.1.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Thu Jun 9
>   16:01:20 PDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> 2. CURL -V
>
> curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3
>   Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2 Protocols: tftp ftp
>   telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp Features:
>   GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
>
> 3. Command Running Status: Without Error

Could you please help give some suggestions on how to make server1 work with curl command? Thank you so much!

Comment: "curl version 7.19.7 was released on November 4 2009" ... **2009** ...

Comment: Red Hat backport fixes in to the software supplied from the repo's. curl 7.19.7 is the version that is from RHEL6 (and therefore also CentOS6). In my recently updated CentOS6 VM's the headline version is still 7.19.7, but it was most recently updated in 2017 according to the change log with a fix for CVE-2017-2628
<br/>
`rpm -q --changelog curl

* Tue Mar 07 2017 Kamil Dudka <kdudka@redhat.com> 7.19.7-53

- treat Negotiate authentication as connection-oriented (CVE-2017-2628) 
... 
`

Answer (score 14):

Thanks all for the help!
Finally I found the solution that using the command like 
curl --tlsv1.2

Comment: I love how there is one  comment and no solution but you still thank people for their support.

Comment: I'm bad lucky, my curl version didn't support --tlsv1.2. I had to upgrade curl to a new version.

Comment: This also worked for my curl-based error: 
    NSS error -5961